# Unable to run junits in eclipse for jhipster sample app gradle

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, jhipster, junit5

I checked out https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-gradle imported the project into eclipse Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0), installed gradle plugin. When I try to run the Junit test Right click -> Run as Junit I keep getting

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/EngineDiscoveryListener
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.getLauncherDiscoveryListener(LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.java:241)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.build(LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit5TestLoader.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/EngineDiscoveryListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.EngineDiscoveryListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
```

I tried searching all over but couldn't find a solution that works, Anybody had the same issue and got it resoled please provide the solution

Comment: Is it possible to tell eclipse to use the gradle test runner instead the internal jdt runner?

Comment: When I Right click, Run as ->  Gradle Test it runs the whole build which is unnecessary

Comment: You mean the frontend part? There are some other things going on as well like annotation processing. If there is no bug gradle should be so smart and detect what to execute and what not. E.g. gradle has executed the frontend build. You change java code and want to execute the according test, the frontend part should not be executed as it is up2date.

Comment: Clearly that is not happening, I don't see any problem running the tests as Junit in a similar maven project. It looks to that eclipse integration with Gradle and Junit 5 is broken

Comment: Did you do "Run As > JUnit Test"? Can you try "Run As > Gradle Test"

Comment: "Run as > Junit Test" doesn't work that is why I opened this Q. "Run as > Gradle test" works however it runs other tests such as npm install etc and the test takes several minutes. Why cant the test run as similar to a maven based project ? Does eclipse need additional plugin ?

Comment: It should be run as gradle test as gradle takes care e.g. of annotation processing. The fact it runs npm stuff is due to process resources which contains the webpack steps. As I said if there is no change it should mark the steps as up-to-date and not execute them. Can you customize the run configuration in eclipse (e.g. adding -x webpack)?

Comment: Are you saying the junit test  of a spring boot gradle project in eclipse should be run as > gradle test only ?

Comment: It depends maybe. At least jetbrains and gradle too recommend using the gradle tooling instead of the ide build in runners.

Answer (score 1):

enthusiast,

Just add

```
testImplementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.5.2')
```

to the dependencies section in **build.gradle** file, refresh gradle (on eclipse, on the context menu of the project > Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project). You should be able to run tests one by one.

Happy coding